# Unable to Port Forward after bridging my modem

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

I have an Arris TG862G modem, and an ASUS RT-AC66U router. My goal is to be able to port forward.

The Arris modem was provided by Comcast, and I have that hooked up to connect to the internet. My ASUS router is then connected to that. I found out that this means I technically have two routers on my network. I first tried to port forward on both devices, but this did not work.

Next, I tried changing my Arris modem to bridge mode so that I am only effectively behind one router. I then tried port forwarding on my ASUS router, but my ports are still listed as unopened.

I'm completely out of ideas on why this is happening.

This is what my ASUS router WAN page looks like:

[image: This is what my ASUS router WAN page looks like]

This is the Port Forwarding Page of my ASUS router:

[image: This is the Port Forwarding Page of my ASUS router]

I want to note that I also do have DMZ enabled at the moment, but I have tried turning that off. I am not really sure whether I should have DMZ enabled. To my understanding, DMZ should have allowed for a point of access to my network from a single computer.

Additionally, I also have NAT enabled too.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to forward WoL. The problem with that is WoL is a broadcast frame, and broadcasts and frames do not cross routers.

It may be possible for you forward it to the LAN broadcast address, rather than a specific IP address. Some routers allow this, and some don't, but that is really allowing anyone on the Internet to broadcast to your network, and that is a very bad idea. It may also not work with WoL.

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't work for any port that I've forwarded. I don't think that WoL is causing the problem